# How do I do run a regex on a regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex pattern and string:

```
var str="Is this all there is?";
var patt1=/is/gi;
```

I would like to just extract the main expression `is` (without the modifiers) from `var patt1` using **another** regular expression, which we can call `var patt2` for arguments sake.

How is this possible to do in vanilla JavaScript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, `patt1` is a regex object.

You could get the regex source by `patt1.source`.

```
> console.dir(patt1);
  /is/gi
    global: true
    ignoreCase: true
    lastIndex: 0
    multiline: false
    source: "is"
    __proto__: /(?:)/
```

Comment: +1 - Accepting this answer only because I saw it first - otherwise there was not much difference between them two :)

Answer (score 9):

No need for a regular expression. Try this:

```
> patt1.source
"is"
```

Comment: +1 - Wow! I had no idea this method existed on the regex object.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this:

```
 var patt1=/[is]/gi;
 alert(patt1.test());
```